# SQL Divide By Zero Error In SELECT Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, case, divide-by-zero

I'm brand new to SQL and could use a hand. I'm getting a divide by zero error with the following in my SELECT statement:

```
SUM(Cast((replace(replace(replace (p.[Total Sales], '$', ''), '(','-'),  ')','')) as money)) - SUM(Cast((replace(replace(replace (p.[Total Cost], '$', ''), '(','-'),  ')','')) as money)) / SUM(Cast((replace(replace(replace (p.[Total Sales], '$', ''), '(','-'),  ')','')) as money)) as new_bal
```

I know that I need to use CASE, but I'm not sure of the application.

Comment: that means for some row your Total Sales are 0, so you can't divide in that case. you could filter out those rows, or use CASE to return another value instead of the division.

Answer (score 5):

You could use **[NULLIF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif)** in following:

`NULLIF(expression1, 0)`

In your case It will be:

```
SUM(Cast((replace(replace(replace (p.[Total Sales], '$', ''), '(','-'),  ')','')) as money)) - SUM(Cast((replace(replace(replace (p.[Total Cost], '$', ''), '(','-'),  ')','')) as money)) / NULLIF(SUM(Cast((replace(replace(replace (p.[Total Sales], '$', ''), '(','-'),  ')','')) as money)),0) as new_bal
```

Comment: You're replacing null with 0 here, which would still result in a divide by zero error...

Comment: No, in this case if expresion1 = 0 It will return NULL.

Comment: @DanField . . . You are confusing the `NULLIF()` function with something else.  It returns `NULL` instead of a divide-by-zero.  As a note:  `NULLIF()` is an ANSI standard function and available in most databases.  It is my preferred way of preventing such errors.

Comment: Ahh sorry for the confusion - I misread it as `IFNULL`.  I've edited the link to point to the MySQL documentation (and also so I could change my mistaken vote ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this portion here:

```
SUM(Cast((replace(replace(replace (p.[Total Sales], '$', ''), '(','-'),  ')','')) as money))
```

alone in a select statement from your table.  You should find that it's sometimes returning zeroes (or perhaps `NULLs`).  You can further debug it by taking out the `SUM` and the `CAST` to find out what replacements you might be missing.

If it turns out you're not missing anything (sometimes the sum is just zero), then here's how you'd use a case statement:

```
CASE 
  WHEN SUM(Cast((replace(replace(replace (p.[Total Sales], '$', ''), '(','-'),  ')','')) as money)) != 0
  THEN SUM(Cast((replace(replace(replace (p.[Total Sales], '$', ''), '(','-'),  ')','')) as money)) - SUM(Cast((replace(replace(replace (p.[Total Cost], '$', ''), '(','-'),  ')','')) as money)) / SUM(Cast((replace(replace(replace (p.[Total Sales], '$', ''), '(','-'),  ')','')) as money)) 
  ELSE 0
END as new_bal
```

As an aside, avoid using spaces or other special characters in column names.  I believe the common standard for MySQL would be smoething like `total_sales`.